# asp.net Summing data in Datatable but missing data in the 1st row and the last row

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a form that gets data from a database (commodityid, name, price,..), add them to a datatable, calculate and return some new columns (totalamount, taxamount), and then sums up the new columns and display the value returned by textboxes.

My problem is when I add new row for the first time, my textboxes display nothing. And for the second time and above, it's not sum the last row. I think there's something wrong in my loop..
How can I fix this? Thank you!

**Adding row for the first time**

[image]

**Second time and above**

[image]

Here is my code:

```
private void AddRow()
{
    if (Session["CurrentTable"] != null)
    {
        DataTable table = (DataTable)Session["CurrentTable"];
        DataRow row = table.NewRow();
        row[0] = ddl_CommodityID.Text.Trim();
        row[1] = txt_CommodityName.Text.Trim();
        row[2] = txt_Unit.Text.Trim();
        decimal price = decimal.Parse(txt_Price.Text.Trim());
        decimal quantity = decimal.Parse(txt_Quantity.Text.Trim());
        decimal taxrate = decimal.Parse(txt_TaxRate.Text.Trim());
        decimal vat = taxrate * quantity * price / 100;
        decimal totalamount = quantity * price;
        row[3] = price;
        row[4] = quantity;
        row[5] = totalamount;
        row[6] = vat;
        for (int i = 0; i <= table.Rows.Count ; i++)
        {
            txt_TotalAmount.Text = table.Compute("Sum(TotalAmount)", "").ToString();
            txt_TotalTax.Text = table.Compute("Sum(VATtax)", "").ToString();
        }
        int insertPosition = table.Rows.Count;
        table.Rows.InsertAt(row, insertPosition);
        CommodityList.DataSource = table;
        CommodityList.DataBind();
        Session["CurrentTable"] = table;
    }
    else
    {
        AddTable();
        DataRow row = table.NewRow();
        row[0] = ddl_CommodityID.Text.Trim();
        row[1] = txt_CommodityName.Text.Trim();
        row[2] = txt_Unit.Text.Trim();
        decimal price = decimal.Parse(txt_Price.Text.Trim());
        decimal quantity = decimal.Parse(txt_Quantity.Text.Trim());
        decimal taxrate = decimal.Parse(txt_TaxRate.Text.Trim());
        decimal vat = taxrate * quantity * price / 100;
        decimal totalamount = quantity * price;
        totalpayment = totalamount + vat;
        row[3] = price;
        row[4] = quantity;
        row[5] = totalamount;
        row[6] = vat;
        for (int i = 0; i <= table.Rows.Count ; i++)
        {
            txt_TotalAmount.Text = table.Compute("Sum(TotalAmount)", "").ToString();
            txt_TotalTax.Text = table.Compute("Sum(VATtax)", "").ToString();
        }
        int insertPosition = table.Rows.Count;
        table.Rows.InsertAt(row, insertPosition);
        CommodityList.DataSource = table;
        CommodityList.DataBind();
        Session["CurrentTable"] = table;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Instead of counting rows from the datatable, I sum the columns from the gridview everytime a row has inserted like this and it worked for me! Thanks!

```
    protected void CommodityList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    decimal totalamount = 0;
    decimal taxamount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < CommodityList.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        String total1 = (CommodityList.Rows[i].Cells[5].Text.Trim());
        totalamount += decimal.Parse(total1);
        String total2 = (CommodityList.Rows[i].Cells[6].Text.Trim());
        taxamount += decimal.Parse(total2);
        totalpayment = totalamount + taxamount;
    }
    txt_TotalAmount.Text = totalamount.ToString();
    txt_TotalTax.Text = taxamount.ToString();
    txt_TotalPayment.Text = totalpayment.ToString();
}
```